# How to swap views, using UIGestureRecognizers

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, uinavigationcontroller, uigesturerecognizer, gesture-recognition

I have set the left back button item of a navigation controller to a custom view and have set up a tap gesture recognizer for it, now when the custom view receives a tap gesture it pops the current view controllers vie of a stack of navigation controllers.

I want to now switch the view when the back button is tapped, and still maintain the functionality similar to a button, like I long press it and it will only pop the current view controller once I have let go.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` to your custom view in addition to the tap recognizer.

Note that `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` is a *continuous* recognizer: one long-press will generate several action messages.  You need to check for state `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded` in your handler.

Comment: ![Twitter Tapped Button](http://stoopidtech.wordpress.com/?attachment_id=158), this is what I want to create.